# How to close the Browse window after uploading an image via automation with Robot Framework?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, robotframework

I need to view my automated browser for furthur actions after image upload but since the browse window is not closing I cannot view the steps proceeding after it. I have tried clicking other parts of the form after image upload but it is not working as well. I performed this automation using Robot Framework.

```
***Keywords***
Upload An Image File
    [Arguments]    ${imagePath}    ${imageName}    ${name}    ${remote_ip}
    ${uploadLocation}=    Get Test Data File Location    ${imagePath}    ${imageName}    ${remote_Ip}
    Click Element    //div[text()='Upload']
    Wait Until Element Is Enabled   id=logo    60
    Choose File    //input[@id='logo']    ${uploadLocation}
    Wait For load    2
```

I am stuck here:
[image: After the browse window opens I am unable to close it]

Comment: you will have to share html code of the popup window in order to close it. However it seems that you have click on open button after upload finishes.

Comment: You may be able to make do by just calling Close Browser and then opening a new instance of the browser.